# Choose one or another URL (node content) depending on the parameters

Tags: 7, uri

I have a site, www.example.com. I have chosen that the Home page is a custom one, which uses a page-custom_home_page.tpl.php. Now I have this new URL: www.example.com/products/*, where * means different parameters (even numerical IDs, etc). I link the URL products with a new node with a different template and everything works perfect. The problem is when I have this URL: www.example.com/*, in which the parameters are after the URL associated to the home page, and I want to use a completely new template. How I do that without module? I am trying to get an exception in template.tpl.php but I am not succeeding and I wonder if there is something I am missing in the concept...

Comment: You should definitely read [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656#page-suggestion) to understand how theme suggestions works.

Comment: I read that page long time ago. Now re-reading do not see a reply to my question. I am using this strategy: in template.tpl.php I see if the selected node has parameters and if these are valid. If not, I suggest a theme. If the parameters are valid, I suggest another theme. The same for the home page, for some reason I was getting a mess with the URL parameters and the already created clean URLs.

Comment: You may need to rephrase your question as it is quite confusing what you are trying to achieve. Especially considering the question seems to revolve mostly around changing a template, but the page title suggests choosing a url.

Comment: as 2pha mentions, the title to this question doesn't seem to match the question, and your last comment doesn't match either the title or the question.  It's now nearly impossible to understand exactly what you're trying to do. If you are actually trying to perform theme switching as your comment suggestions, that cannot be done without a module, I would suggest the Themekey module